# Reading CSV file from a a secured link with J

Tags: curl, j

I'm trying to get CSV file from https://www.alphavantage.co/ and pass values to J to process.

I tried httpget and web/gethttp (based on curl) but hit a wall with both, as for httpget I don't know how to pass https to httpget function.
I couldn't get gethttp to work at all.

link will look like this (this is a demo link) : 
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo&datatype=csv

my trial with httpget is giving this error:

```
|domain error: httpget
   log    ;:^:_1 host;(":port);path
```

How can I use J to get online csv and pass it to my code? thanks.

Edit: this is my platform

```
Engine: j901/j64/linux
Beta-c: commercial/2019-04-03T10:18:09
Library: 9.01.03
Qt IDE: 1.8.1/5.5.1
Platform: Linux 64
Installer: J901 install
InstallPath: /home/sam/j901
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the link you give above, the following works for me on Windows 10:

```
   load 'web/gethttp csv'
   Link=: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo&datatype=csv'
   fixcsv gethttp Link
┌───────────────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│timestamp          │open    │high    │low     │close   │volume  │
├───────────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│2019-04-18 16:00:00│123.3900│123.5000│123.3000│123.3700│1327949 │
├───────────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│2019-04-18 15:55:00│123.4100│123.4800│123.3000│123.3900│931359  │
├───────────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│2019-04-18 15:50:00│123.3250│123.4200│123.2900│123.4100│340777  │
└───────────────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
...

      JVERSION
Engine: j807/j64/windows
Release-d: commercial/2019-03-18T13:21:35
Library: 8.07.25
Qt IDE: 1.7.9s/5.9.6
Platform: Win 64
Installer: J807 install
InstallPath: c:/program files/j64-807
Contact: www.jsoftware.com
```

For Linux it appears that an additional set of double quotes seems to be required for the link to be correctly interpreted by `curl` or `wget`:

```
   fixcsv gethttp dquote Link
┌───────────────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│timestamp          │open    │high    │low     │close   │volume  │
├───────────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│2019-04-18 16:00:00│123.3900│123.5000│123.3000│123.3700│1327949 │
├───────────────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
...
```

The double quoting works fine for Windows too so potentially you can just double quote the link and it should work across platforms.

Comment: applying above code (similar to my trials) ; it gives empty line. I'm using ubuntu with J9b

Comment: If I just try raw curl or wget in an Ubuntu terminal with that link I get errors too (invalid apikey or similar). Adding double quotes around the string seems to fix things. Works inside J tool. Will update my answer.